# I want slick carousel to display pictures of different size one at time in center mode but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I am having a problem with slick slider from keewheeler for a while now. I tried to create a carousel that display pictures of different size but the the problem is when I am trying to use the center mode, the next and previous sliders are showing aside of the centered slider.

I tried to use such properties as: sliderToShow, centerPadding and others css solutions such as: box-sizing: border-box etc... nothing worked as I excepted and I am clueless

The code that generate the carousel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.sliderslick').slick({
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '0px',
                variableWidth: true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                arrows: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 5000,
                cssEase: 'ease'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The css code I tried to use to fix the problem:

```
.slick-slide img {
    max-height: 398px;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and just in case the html part that is supposed to be the carrousel:

```
<div class="sliderslick">


                                    <div>
                                        <img src="Chambre_hote/chambrePoetic1.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
                                    </div><!-- Slide1-->
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="Chambre_hote/chambrePoetic2.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
                                    </div><!-- Slide2-->
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="Chambre_hote/chambrePoetic3.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
                                    </div><!-- Slide3-->
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="Chambre_hote/chambrePoetic4.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
                                    </div><!-- Slide4-->
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="Chambre_hote/chambrePoetic5.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
                                    </div><!-- Slide5-->

                                </div>
```

I only expect that only the main slider is display, not the previous nor the next one.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you can't have `variableWidth` set to true and only one slide at a time. It's a conflict in itself.

There is a way around that. You can create a container for each image that has the same width and center your image in that container. That way, you'll have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked. Now I just have a problem with the vertical pictures and slick doesn't seem to center them. I will fix that

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want to achieve but Slick Slider has a property adaptiveHeight: true to resize the slider according to the height of the image. If you want all slides to have the same height and vertically center the content inside it, I suggest you look into flexbox. This website gives a pretty good explanation : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/